# Android 10: GATT error with 133 - how fix?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have android app. I use BLE(Bluetooth low energy) for connect to devices. It is work good, but I have issue on Android 10. This is my code:

```
 Hashtable<String, BluetoothDevice> myHtDevices;
 ....
 BluetoothGatt gatt = myHtDevices.get(deviceId).connectGatt(this, false, gattCallback);
```

in onConnectionStateChange I get:

```
//public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState){
status= 133,
newStatus =0,
```

I have this issue only Android Q.

I tried this method(add param TRANSPORT_LE), but it not work:

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
        gatt = myHtDevices.get(deviceId).connectGatt(this, false, gattCallback, 
     BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE);
    }
    else {
        gatt = myHtDevices.get(deviceId).connectGatt(this, false, gattCallback);
    }
```

Add info:

1. I get myHtDevices by performing a BLE scan.
2. I callback come immediately.
3. Device- Samsung 9

This is nRF Connect log:

```
  nRF Connect, 2020-03-24
    Device (50:8C:B1:52:B7:8D)
V  19:37:26.248  Connecting to 50:8C:B1:52:B7:8D...
D  19:37:26.248  gatt = device.connectGatt(autoConnect = false, TRANSPORT_LE, preferred PHY = LE 1M)
D  19:37:26.549  [Broadcast] Action received: android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED
D  19:37:26.721  [Callback] Connection state changed with status: 0 and new state: CONNECTED (2)
I  19:37:26.721  Connected to 50:8C:B1:52:B7:8D
V  19:37:26.745  Discovering services...
D  19:37:26.745  gatt.discoverServices()
I  19:37:26.872  Connection parameters updated (interval: 7.5ms, latency: 0, timeout: 5000ms)
D  19:37:27.768  [Callback] Services discovered with status: 0
I  19:37:27.768  Services discovered
V  19:37:27.814  Generic Access (0x1800)
- Device Name [R] (0x2A00)
- Appearance [R] (0x2A01)
- Peripheral Privacy Flag [R W] (0x2A02)
- Reconnection Address [W] (0x2A03)
- Peripheral Preferred Connection Parameters [R] (0x2A04)
Generic Attribute (0x1801)
- Service Changed [I] (0x2A05)
   Client Characteristic Configuration (0x2902)
Device Information (0x180A)
- System ID [R] (0x2A23)
- Model Number String [R] (0x2A24)
- Serial Number String [R] (0x2A25)
- Firmware Revision String [R] (0x2A26)
- Hardware Revision String [R] (0x2A27)
- Software Revision String [R] (0x2A28)
- Manufacturer Name String [R] (0x2A29)
- IEEE 11073-20601 Regulatory Certification Data List [R] (0x2A2A)
- PnP ID [R] (0x2A50)
Unknown Service (6d95c372-02f0-4360-b0c0-432109c2b715)
- Unknown Characteristic [R W WNR] (105998c0-5e55-4de3-9fc9-1cf857231477)
   Characteristic User Description (0x2901)
- Unknown Characteristic [R W WNR] (4f294974-26c0-43f6-aff9-aac109231e0d)
   Characteristic User Description (0x2901)
- Unknown Characteristic [R W WNR] (51bb9208-7ed1-4c10-821a-be0ca1880c36)
   Characteristic User Description (0x2901)
- Unknown Characteristic [R W WNR] (1767ac17-5aac-4692-93b0-1cb11b28fda6)
   Characteristic User Description (0x2901)
- Unknown Characteristic [R W WNR] (3242c75b-0ce2-4560-9cc4-5190b2ee93d3)
   Characteristic User Description (0x2901)
- Unknown Characteristic [R W WNR] (ad2192c7-c2d0-4c2a-b705-194602bf3c9e)
   Characteristic User Description (0x2901)
Unknown Service (18b794e2-9679-4676-93e1-6a244758002d)
- Unknown Characteristic [R W WNR] (b8fe10c6-eba1-425d-849c-189e60f4dbc9)
   Characteristic User Description (0x2901)
- Unknown Characteristic [R W WNR] (fd8c491c-e597-4e85-b831-5b4c37a3afc6)
   Characteristic User Description (0x2901)
Unknown Service (bd31f74c-7f33-4b27-a2cf-6660b8d1efc2)
- Unknown Characteristic [R W WNR] (e91ed239-2e78-4aa9-8f5a-9701ecac4740)
   Characteristic User Description (0x2901)
- Unknown Characteristic [R W WNR] (6e143748-ac59-4522-bdd0-46fd3e2101d7)
   Characteristic User Description (0x2901)
- Unknown Characteristic [R W WNR] (b1e20318-8afc-47e3-3ac2-1eea626ce7a9)
   Characteristic User Description (0x2901)
Unknown Service (baefe645-2991-4f24-9fb1-a8ea687c395a)
- Unknown Characteristic [R W WNR] (898542a6-55e6-4188-ac49-261d3e179640)
   Characteristic User Description (0x2901)
- Unknown Characteristic [R W WNR] (06dc3129-99e3-45e6-8694-8845ce52fdda)
   Characteristic User Description (0x2901)
- Unknown Characteristic [R W WNR] (d49aeb6d-a33c-4cf0-a06f-f7eca72bfe4f)
   Characteristic User Description (0x2901)
- Unknown Characteristic [R W WNR] (583205af-5509-42ed-bdac-f95bb5c7bca3)
   Characteristic User Description (0x2901)
- Unknown Characteristic [R W WNR] (fa54cb0c-ca4f-405d-b8e0-cf3c7d2f5ffe)
   Characteristic User Description (0x2901)
- Unknown Characteristic [R W WNR] (b1e20318-8afc-47e3-a32c-e1ae26c67e9a)
   Characteristic User Description (0x2901)
D  19:37:27.815  gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, true)
I  19:37:27.840  Connection parameters updated (interval: 48.75ms, latency: 0, timeout: 5000ms)
```

Any advices?

Comment: How do you get the BluetoothDevice object? By manually entering Bluetooth device address or by performing a BLE scan? Also, does the callback come immediately or after 30 seconds? And which phone do you have?

Comment: Could you try using the app nRFConnect to connect to your device? There is a log feature there, could you post the output? Also logcat output would be nice to see if there are any messages coming from the Bluetooth stack.

Comment: I added nRF Connect log

Comment: Ok so that app successfully connects so something must be wrong in your code. Can you please post the FULL code instead, or even better, a minimal example of a FULL code that still reproduces the issue, where you have removed irrelevant stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your help. but this problem is only on android 10, on younger versions it works fine. I'll think about whether I can create minimal example

Comment: You are scanning so I don't think this is the issue but for any poor fellow like myself trawling the internet for Android 10 issues I discovered that if you don't scan before connecting on Android 10 you will get a Gatt 133. I resolved the issue by checking if paired and if not doing a scan. Disable/Enable BT before you test to confirm.

Answer (score 9):

As seen in the [AOSP constants](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/adc9f28ad418356cb81640059b59eee4d862e6b4/stack/include/gatt_api.h#54), this error is the most generic error you can get. Generally, it happens when the device is out of range but you tried to connect anyway. You should check the full logcat & dmesg to find out the root cause. My BLE app fails to connect to any devices on Huawei phones running custom ROMs, so make sure that the device is on the OEM stock version of Android 10 - and if that doesn't work, try on AOSP instead - you never know what a manufacturer put in their skin.