# BLE GATT getting disconnected sometimes after connection with exception 'GattCallback error: 133' in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm implementing BLE in Xamarin forms. I'm able to do all the BLE operation read, write and notification. But sometimes the device gets disconnected after connection. This is the exception I get

> **Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Exceptions.DeviceConnectionException:** 'GattCallback error: 133'

This is the code where I'm doing the connection

```
 private async Task ScanForDevices(ScanData scanData)
        {
            
            _adapter = CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter;
            _adapter.ScanMode = ScanMode.LowLatency;
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                _adapter.DeviceDiscovered += async (s, a) =>
            {
                NativeDeviceAdd = DependencyService.Get<INativeDevice>().ConvertToNative(a.Device);
                PropertyInfo propInfo = NativeDeviceAdd.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
                BleDeviceName = (string)propInfo.GetValue(NativeDeviceAdd, null);
               
                string substr = scanData.blename;
                if (BleDeviceName == substr)
                {
                  
                     _device = a.Device;
                   
                   await _adapter.StopScanningForDevicesAsync();
                   await ConnectForDevice(_characteristicsBLE);

                }
            };
            });
            await _adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();
        }


       
        private async Task ConnectForDevice(ICharacteristic characteristics)
        {
           
            await _adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(_device);
        }
```

These are the logs.

```
01-08 17:31:50.435 D/BluetoothManager(26670): getConnectionState()
01-08 17:31:50.435 D/BluetoothManager(26670): getConnectedDevices
01-08 17:31:50.439 D/BluetoothGatt(26670): connect() - device: 34:C9:F0:8D:F4:57, auto: false
01-08 17:31:50.439 D/BluetoothGatt(26670): registerApp()
01-08 17:31:50.439 D/BluetoothGatt(26670): registerApp() - UUID=84c84faa-46ff-4e02-9f9a-f8d14fed8ed0
01-08 17:31:50.441 D/BluetoothGatt(26670): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=13
01-08 17:31:51.587 D/BluetoothGatt(26670): onClientConnectionState() - status=133 clientIf=13 device=34:C9:F0:8D:F4:57
01-08 17:31:51.594 D/BluetoothGatt(26670): onClientConnectionState() - status=133 clientIf=12 device=34:C9:F0:8D:F4:57
Thread started:  #10
Thread started:  #11
01-08 17:31:51.680 D/BluetoothGatt(26670): close()
01-08 17:31:51.680 D/BluetoothGatt(26670): close()
01-08 17:31:51.680 D/BluetoothGatt(26670): unregisterApp() - mClientIf=12
01-08 17:31:51.680 D/BluetoothGatt(26670): unregisterApp() - mClientIf=13
**Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Exceptions.DeviceConnectionException:** 'GattCallback error: 133'
```

I'm not getting any solution for this from Xamarin side. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by  specifying the transport type to the **ConnectToDeviceAsync** method like this:

```
var parameters = new ConnectParameters(forceBleTransport: true);
await _adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(deviceToConnect, parameters, cancellationToken.Token);
```

still I got  this issue sometimes so I checked the **BLE explorer app** in play store and found that issue is with the advertiser.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately error 133 is relatively common and is usually related to the hardware/stack (especially if this is happening on Android). It has no clearly defined fix yet (as far as I know) but there have been mentions of a few workarounds, including attempting to silently reconnect or attempting to create a bond. Have a look at the link below and search for "133" for more info on the workaround:-

- [Ultimate Guide to Android BLE Development](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/?utm_source=BlogEmail&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=BlogRoundUp&mc_cid=9113555d36&mc_eid=767bbcdc1b)

Also some references on what some other users have tried:-

- [GATT Error 133 on onConnectionStateChange](https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/issues/18)
- [Android 10 with GATT Error 133](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60810522/android-10-gatt-error-with-133-how-fix)
- [GATT Error 133 with Android](https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless-connectivity/bluetooth/f/538/t/534737?GATT-error-133-on-ANDROID)
- [Making Android BLE Work](https://medium.com/@martijn.van.welie/making-android-ble-work-part-2-47a3cdaade07)
- [Lessons for Android BLE Developers](https://android.jlelse.eu/lessons-for-first-time-android-bluetooth-le-developers-i-learned-the-hard-way-fee07646624)