# Android BLE on Xiaomi T11 completely broken behaviour

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt, xiaomi

Im currently trying to figure out why some Android devices have problem with our Bluetooth Low Energy app.

Working with this I am running the same codebase&app on my Samsung S22 and Xiaomi T11 or OnePlus Nord2.

Its a simple Bluetooth Low Energy app where I send data to a peripheral/server

My Samsung works perfectly good sending and reading data from the GATT device, my Xiaomi T11 not so much. Here's a sample log:

```
08-10 16:31:21.642 21053 21071 V Wrote descriptor for e5694fc9 status 0
08-10 16:31:21.647 21053 21071 V Transmitting 10 bytes
08-10 16:31:21.657 21053 21069 V Device received the data (onCharacteristicWrite) GATT status: 128
08-10 16:31:21.671 21053 21069 V Transmitting 10 bytes
08-10 16:31:21.677 21053 21069 V Device received the data (onCharacteristicWrite) GATT status: 128
08-10 16:31:21.719 21053 21069 V Done sending, awaiting response from peripheral
08-10 16:31:21.727 21053 21069 V Device received the data (onCharacteristicWrite) GATT status: 133
```

As you can see, there's GATT status 128 (NO_RESOURCE), and status 133 (generic?)

This does NOT happen on my Samsung.

SDK target version 33,
Both devices run Android 13.

This issue is most likely affecting these devices as well because they all have the **Mediatek chipset**:
One plus Nord2, Oppo, Motorola

Does anyone have an idea of what the issue is and how to resolve it?

Testing all sorts of implementations of BLE GATT.

Edit:
I have found that the error occurs when I send an empty byte array to the peripheral, so it seems like the MediaTek chipset hardware stack doesn't like when the payload (byte array) is empty.

Comment: So I have found that I cannot send an empty byte array with my Xiaomi which has MediaTek, but my Samsung will... This is party of our communication protocol, which we have used for 8 years in production.

What is this symptom of? MediaTek bad implementation of BLE standard?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately these are generic Android errors that are known but don't have a valid fix yet. They are related to the hardware/stack on the Android phone and your best bet is to implement a workaround. In this case the workaround would be to try and reconnect when you get a disconnection because of status 128 or status 133. I have also read that attempting to bond with the remote device can also fix the issue sometimes. Have a look at the links below for more information:-

- [BLE GATT getting disconnection sometimes with error 133](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65629978/ble-gatt-getting-disconnected-sometimes-after-connection-with-exception-gattcal/65662801#65662801)
- [Android issue tracker - Status 133](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/269646835)
- [Making Android BLE work - part 2](https://medium.com/@martijn.van.welie/making-android-ble-work-part-2-47a3cdaade07)
- [Lessons for Android developers](https://medium.com/android-news/lessons-for-first-time-android-bluetooth-le-developers-i-learned-the-hard-way-fee07646624)
- [The ultimate guide to Android BLE](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/?utm_source=BlogEmail&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=BlogRoundUp&mc_cid=9113555d36&mc_eid=767bbcdc1b)

Comment: It indeed looks like its part of the hardware/stack, see my comment on my post.